# File Permission For Zip File Java

Tags: java, zip, posix, file-permissions

Our **web application** is hosted in `Linux` machine which is used to upload files and create zip of it and download option. I have set file permission using `setPosixFilePermissions()` method and if they access app from Windows machine and download will be the permissions of the file retain? if I have to retain what are the option. Please help me to solve this.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file permission that you set using setPosixFilePermission() is for how can your web application access this file. When user login to your application, the file permission will be stored base on their browser settings, their OS settings. This is not related to how the server side file permission.

Comment: So basically you are saying we cannot have same permission as in server and handling client permission is not in control

Comment: That's correct, because you serve the file via your application.